# SNOWFLAKE COPY Command not copying data inside

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Im getting started with Snowflake and something I dont understand. I tried to issue a copy command as below but it shows no rows processed.

```
copy into customer
  from @bulk_copy_example_stage
  FILES = ('dataDec-9-2020.csv')
  file_format = (type = csv field_delimiter = '|' skip_header = 1)
  FORCE=TRUE;
```

I tried with another file from the same S3 folder

```
copy into customer
  from @bulk_copy_example_stage
  FILES = ('generated_customer_data.csv')
  file_format = (type = csv field_delimiter = '|' skip_header = 1)
  FORCE=TRUE;
```

And this worked.

At this stage im pretty sure that something was wrong with my first file. but my question is, how do we get to print out what the error was? all it shows in the console is as below which is not really helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking at the copy_history to find out what's wrong with the file.

Reference: [copy_history](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/copy_history.html)

Comment: I tried that but it showed the status of loaded but no errors.

Comment: Check if the filename matches, check the file path. If that doesn't work, please open a support case.